# Skrollr.js hash url as it gets to content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using skrollr.js (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) how can I change the hash on the URL as it gets to the content just like in the example here: www.soleilnoir.net/believein? Skrollr has a hash plugin but it is only on clicking a link (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-menu) - I'd love to implement it where on click or on scroll to that section it places the hash anchor in the url..

Comment: It's planned, but not scheduled https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-menu/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the skrollr.js but here's something you could try out:

You probably have multiple content areas ("pages") just give them all the .section class name and individual id by the content they're going to have, eg. #home, #about etc.

As you get to the content, which would have a class .section and id #about, you get the id value of that section. When you have it just set it to the address bar hash.

```
var sectionID = $elem.attr('id');
window.location.hash = sectionID;
```

Comment: Won't work, because it will jump to the hash while scrolling. Additionally, on mobile skrollr doesn't actually scroll, but uses CSS transform. You need to use `pushState`there